# Linking sql database table using Mamp with php

Tags: php, sql, database, mamp

I am making a text-based adventure game with php and databases in Mamp.

I have put the room descriptions into a table with an id number for each room. However, I cant get the table from sql, I always get a HTTP ERROR 500.

I know the database connects as the page loads if I take out $sql - ?>.

The php code looks like:

```
<?php

// Extract the page data from the d/b
// define the constants
// note best practice is to keep these separate so values can be 
changed easily
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "1234";
$dbname = "Room";

// Create connection using the above values
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// extract values from d/b
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Room, Rooms'; // build the query string
$result = $conn->query($sql);   // execute the query - sends back a 
list of records
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();      // select the first row/record
$description = $row['RoomDesc'];    // select the description of the 
room
?>
```

Comment: 'changed easily' is meant to be part of the previous note

Comment: There are a few comments which have broken over lines, perhaps edit the question to get these on one line? Also - I have added an answer, please let me know if this helps :)

Comment: If you have found an answer to your question, please mark it as "accepted"

Comment: you have a typo. It is Room.Rooms if you have a table Rooms inside the db Room. Anyway Room, Rooms is not valid mysql

Answer (score 0):

`$conn` is a link to the database, not an object of type MySQLi, you 500 because you are trying to call a function on a non-object, instead, you need to do something such as;

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);   // execute the query - sends back a list of records
```

As well as this, the function to get records is;

```
$row = $result->fetchAssoc();
```

This is because you are using procedural and not the OOP methodology

You can also use the following to see what errors you are getting;

```
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

As per comments on Q, you have an error in the SQL, you do `SELECT * FROM Room, Rooms` which is not valid, you can only use one `FROM`, you can join tables however, fix your SQL and you'll fix your issues

Without seeing the database - we can't help with fixing that

Comment: still getting the same error, not sure how to implement the bottom code to see the specific error.